# Injecting PHP data into JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php

What's the preferred way of outputting PHP code within apostrophes? For example this JavaScript code would break and the second line will be totally empty:

```
var jsString = '<div id="content">'+'<?php echo $something['1'] ?>'+'</div>';
```

Thanks! I know this is kind of basic and I know how to fix it, but I'm wondering how to do it the right way?

[edit]

I know it looks obvious, but `$something["1"]` won't work. The same goes for `$something[\'1\']`.

Comment: PHP doesn't interpret anything outside the `<?php ?>` tags, so the Javascript stuff is irrelevant.

Comment: I think this should have been tagged with javascript and not PHP.

Comment: @Lix not really, because this has nothing to do with javascript (other than the fact that he's using js in his example).

Comment: @ken **The OP wants to know how to correctly escape a string in JS.** The fact that the string that needs to be escaped is PHP is irrelevant. The same question could be asked about printing python or C# in JavaScript. The programming language being used is JavaScript.

Comment: It might help to tell us what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to store a string that will later be executed by PHP? Or are you trying to add a PHP value to a javascript string?

Comment: Are you trying to output the results of the PHP code, or are you trying to literally include the text `<?php...` in the Javascript string?

Comment: @Lix: That's the case if the OP is trying to emit PHP code with JS.  That's possible, but unlikely.  At the very least, the OP needs to clarify ;)

Comment: I'm storing a WordPress option (plain text within a variable) and want to output it to the front-end, as a text too :) The JS generates a dynamic box and it should contain text you set on the back-end.

Comment: This is unanswerable if you're not just going to reject `$something[\'1\']` out of hand without telling us why it won't work.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you asking how to do this : `'<?php echo $something['1'] ?>'`, or this: `$something['1']`?

Comment: @Lix no, the question is in summarization: "why isn't `<?php echo $something['1']; ?>` not working?" the example can easily be something like `<p class='<?php echo $something['1']; ?>'>` and it would be the same question.

Comment: We need to know more about what he's doing.  Is he trying to inject PHP code into the javascript that gets read by the browser (e. g. inserting a value for javascript to then read later), or is he trying to inject a string into javascript that happens to be PHP?

Comment: meagar, with `\'1\'` I'm getting this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''1\']; ?>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in (...)`

Comment: RonLugge, I'm tryng to inject a a string into JS and this string happens to be PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example is working well for me :

```
<?php
$something['1']='hhhh0';
 ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var jsString = '<div id="content">'+'<?php echo $something['1'] ;?>'+'</div>';
    alert(jsString);
</script>
```

Comment: I think I've found what the problem was, and it had nothing to do with apostrophes after all. Try storing line breaks in $something['1']. Does it work too? Even json_encode() won't help as there are some HTML tags in there. Ugh.

Comment: @Wordpressor What does your actual data look like? I tried this solution with a line break and HTML tags and it seemed to work: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/j19-vvc

Comment: @showdev, I think I'm going to ask another question, my data comes from a textarea and user inputs it, it can contain any HTML tags, so it might be, for example: `<h1>A header</h1>` [user hits enter here for the next line] `<p>something else</p>` [another enter for new line] etc. I guess all I need to do is to replace every new line with `'+` although it doesn't seem to be an easy thing to do.

Comment: @Wordpressor i suggest to user `strip_tags()` function in php to eliminate every tag in the post variable , pay attention to injections and xss attacks

Comment: @FaceOfJock, what if I want the tags there? I guess it will take a lot of effort to accomplish?

Comment: @no problem this example is working with tags , i tought you want to display those tags in alert :P , sorry :)